# Does Genghish Khan Worship Tengri?

Tags: mongol-empire

> Tengri is the intelligence and power behind all of nature. Everything
>   is ultimately controlled by him, from the weather to the fate of
>   individuals and nations, which is why Genghis Khan says in the Altan
>   Tobchi: 'I have not become Lord thanks to my own bravery and strength,
>   I have become Lord thanks to the love of our mighty father Tengri. I
>   have defeated my enemies thanks to the assistance of our father
>   Tengri. I have not become Khan thanks to my own all-embracing prowess.
>   I have become Lord thanks to the love of our father Khan Tengri. I
>   have defeated alien enemies thanks to the mercy of our father Khan
>   Tengri.'

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengrism

Comment: I am tempted to create a *lazy-question* tag for this ...

Comment: Didn't know he had a religion.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I think you should state so much as part of the question. And not to be picky about language (I'm also not a native speaker): the verbatim answer to "Does Ghenghish Khan ..." would be "No" (for he is long dead and the [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan) is spelled differently). Anyway, you got your answer, so that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Wiki you linked:

> Tengriism also played a large part in the religious denomination of the Gok-Turk Empire and the Great Mongol Empire. The name “Gok-Turk” translates as “Celestial Turk” which directly points out to the devotion to Tengriism. In the 13th century, Genghis Khan and several generations of his followers were also Tengrian believers until his fifth generation descendent Uzbeg Khan turned to Islam in the 14th century.